# Ler XML tags específicas?

Tags: c#, xml

Preciso fazer a leitura de `tags` específicas desse arquivo `XML`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EnviarLoteRpsEnvio xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns="http://www.abrasf.org.br/nfse">
<LoteRps Id="Lote4">
    <NumeroLote>4</NumeroLote>
    <Cnpj>07160720000111</Cnpj>
    <InscricaoMunicipal>00500787</InscricaoMunicipal>
    <QuantidadeRps>1</QuantidadeRps>        
</LoteRps>
```

Por exemplo: estou utilizando esse código para ler as informações `tag` `Cnpj` meu código tem um botão(`btnLerTag_Click`) que serve para alimentar um `Listbox`(`lstXML`).

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace LendoXML
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnLerTag_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        XmlDocument oXML = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNodeList oNoLista = default(XmlNodeList);                
        string ArquivoXML = txtCaminhoXML.Text;                
        oXML.Load(ArquivoXML);
        oNoLista = oXML.SelectNodes("/EnviarLoteRpsEnvio/LoteRps/Cnpj");

        foreach (XmlNode oNo in oNoLista)
        {
            lstXML.Items.Add(oNo.ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Eu consigo ler a `tag` `CNPJ` tranquilamente se eu deixar meu `XML` assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EnviarLoteRpsEnvio>
  <LoteRps Id="Lote4">
    <NumeroLote>4</NumeroLote>
```

Porém se o `XML` estiver na forma original com aquelas informações adicionais dentro da `tag` ***EnviarLoteRpsEnvio*** eu não consigo ler a `tag` `CNPJ`.

[EDIT]

Código fornecido pelo Virgilio que resolveu o problema:
Só fiz algumas alterações nele

```
 private void btnLerTag_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("n", "http://www.abrasf.org.br/nfse");

        XmlDocument oXML = new XmlDocument();
        string ArquivoXML = txtCaminhoXML.Text;           
        oXML.Load(ArquivoXML);
        XmlNode root = oXML.DocumentElement;            
        XmlNodeList oNoLista = root.SelectNodes("//n:Cnpj", nsmgr);

        foreach (XmlNode oNo in oNoLista)
        {
            lstXML.Items.Add(oNo.ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ele possui o `namespace` (`xmlns`) contido no arquivo, então, para resolver esse problema seria:

```
private void btnLerTag_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    //declaração do namespace      
    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("n", "http://www.abrasf.org.br/nfse");        

    XmlDocument oXML = new XmlDocument();
    string ArquivoXML = txtCaminhoXML.Text;                
    oXML.Load(ArquivoXML);
    XmlNode root = oXML.DocumentElement;             
    XmlNodeList oNoLista = root.SelectNodes("//n:Cnpj", nsmgr);

    foreach (XmlNode oNo in oNoLista)
    {
        lstXML.Items.Add(oNo.ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText);
    }
}
```

<sub>**Referencias**</sub>

- [Selecionar nós usando a navegação XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/d271ytdx(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Método XmlNode.SelectSingleNode (String, XmlNamespaceManager)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/h0hw012b(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode and xmlNamespace issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171451/xmldocument-selectsinglenode-and-xmlnamespace-issue)

Comment: Bom dia Virgilio,

Seu código estava com algumas coisas erradas, mas está funcional. Fiz algumas alterações e funcionou. Editei minha pergunta e adicionei o código corrigido.

Só mais uma dúvida, se eu tiver mais que uma tag CNPJ no arquivo XML, como faço para pesquisar por uma tag CNPJ específica?
Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @Thiagopsw o meu código não tem problemas, inclusive testado, agora a adaptação para o seu você quem faz não é? Outra duvida outra pergunta tudo bem! o site funciona assim. se for útil assinale como resposta da sua pergunta, se não tudo bem.

Comment: Eu só citei um "problema" no seu code devido ao fato de conter dois objetos com o mesmo nome (**oNoLista**) do tipo  'XmlNodeList '. Aqui só funcionou o algoritmo depois de remover uma dessas declarações.

Comment: Ok @Thiagopsw, vlw

Answer (score 0):

olá, acho que a formatação do seu xml está errada. Verifica esse site que explica a estrutura de um arquivo xml: https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/.

Comment: Não está errada a formatação. Esse é um xml de uma NFSe do sistema da empresa aonde eu trabalho. Mesmo assim, agradeço pela tentativa de ajudar.